# What to call someone who buys only certain products (e.g. vegetables) from a certain store?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've thought of the term "selective", but this seems to suggest that he/she picks his/her products carefully.

Instead, I'd like to place emphasis on the fact that he/she buys only a certain **type** of products from this store.

Comment: Maybe "choosy"?

Comment: Why not say “she bought only vegetables at Pierre’s,” or “She bought all her vegetables at Pierre’s”? This leaves open the question of her reasons.

Comment: I agree with Xanne: there is no noun that covers such a person - a description is required. You could say "When it comes to buying <insert produce>, her loyalty to <insert store name> is total."

Comment: I'd say 'selective' is the only adjective used hereabouts, and while it's not a perfect fit, it is probably close enough for most purposes. 'Choosy' and 'picky' imply 'fussy', not 'prudent' / 'discerning'. But Xanne's suggestion is how almost all people would convey the detailed information. No short cuts that don't lose precision.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question. There's at least two possible interpretations, and I don't know what you mean.  1) she buys only vegetables from this shop, but doesn't buy cheese or meat there 2) she buys vegetables  only from this shop, she won't buy them anywhere else.

Comment: Particular....?

Comment: This is such a very particular description. Are you sure it must be products from a store? Could it be say items on a menu? or clothes from a particular store? or anything about anything? What are your 'must haves'?

Answer (score 1):

***choosy***

> difficult to please because you are very exact about what you like:

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/choosy)

Comment: Or ***particular***

Answer (score 1):

I think "brand-conscious" or "brand-loyal" might be it.  (Using brand to indicate the particular retailer, not necessarily the product which may not carry a noticeable brand.)

Answer (score 0):

The shopper could be "habitual" to further imply they are regular and predictable in their purchases.

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/habitual)

> adjective
>
> > of the nature of a habit; fixed by or resulting from habit: habitual courtesy.
> >
> > being such by habit: a habitual gossip.
> >
> > commonly used, followed, observed, etc., as by a particular person; customary: She took her habitual place at the table.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to place emphasis on the fact that he/she buys only a certain
> type of products from this store.

*She is product-selective when she shops there*

or

*She is product-directed when she shops there*

---

**EDIT**

I originally included the following possibilty

*She is product-biased when she shops there*

However user405662 comments "selectiveness need not imply bias."

I could appeal to the following definition

> the fact of preferring a particular subject or thing:
>
> She showed a scientific bias at an early age.
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bias

... but the primary definition of bias usually refers to "unfair" preference. What unfairness signifies with regard to shopping is debatable, but I will concede the point.

Comment: _selectiveness_ need not imply _bias_.

Comment: @user405662 - Good point. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> *invariable*: not changing or capable of change : CONSTANT ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invariable))

or

> *inveterate*: firmly established by long persistence. ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inveterate))

Answer (score 0):

What about "single-item shopper" or using the item in question as the descriptor/adjective?

"Apple-seeking shopper hits pay dirt at Bob's Market."

"Apple-seeker finds missing ingredient at Bob's Market."

"Apples-only shopper, Mrs. Smith, pleased by Bob's bushels of Braeburns."

Sounds goofy, I guess.

You could also say something like, "Shopper on an apple mission/quest/search, Mrs. Smith, found what she needed at Bob's Market." It doesn't necessarily mean that she didn't buy anything else, but it's pretty clear that she did find the one item she wanted: apples.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer.